# zip a directory into a Resource during build only when input files changed

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a C# project using an SDK-style project file.

During the build, I want the contents of an input folder to be zipped up and included as a Resource in the built binary. This .zip resource should be rebuilt if there are changes to the input folder, or of course if the .zip file doesn't exist yet.

Based on some related questions on this site, I have made a project file using the [ZipDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/zipdirectory-task?view=vs-2022) task. It tries to [build incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2022) rather than blanket recreating the .zip on every build, and here is where I get into trouble. Below is the simplest project file I can come up with:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Build the input files into a .zip file and mark it as a Resource -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Inputs Include="inputs\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="RebuildZip" Inputs="@(Inputs)" Outputs="output.zip" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ZipDirectory SourceDirectory="inputs" DestinationFile="output.zip" Overwrite="true" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <Resource Include="output.zip" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The immediate problem is that the `RebuildZip` target never gets run (confirmed by adding a `<Message>` task inside the Target). My hypothesis is that the 'incremental' part of the build system hasn't decided that output.zip needs to be created. But putting the `<Resource Include="output.zip" />` outside the Target doesn't seem to trigger the Target to be run.

If I remove `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes from the `Target` tag, the task is run successfully, but on every build, which is too often.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can make the change in VS.  First make sure you added the object to the project.  It should appear the the Solution Explorer.  If not than use menu Add Existing Item and browse for the object.  Then right click object in the Solution Explorer and select Properties.  There is a copy option where you can select copy when changed.

Comment: what should `$inputs`  in  `<Inputs Include="$inputs\**\*" />`  do? Is it a typo that you didn't enclose that parenthesis like so `($inputs)`?

Comment: @rene ah yes that is a typo. You can ignore the `$`. I will edit it out. I was just giving a sample path for the input files to be zipped up.

Comment: Is the 'inputs' directory a static part of the project or is it dynamically created and populated? The `ItemGroup` that defines the `Inputs` item collection is 'run' in the evaluation phase. Targets are 'run' in the execution phase after evaluation. But if the 'inputs' directory is dynamically created I would expect that if the `build` target is run twice (with no intervening `clean` or `rebuild`) that the second `build` would work.

Comment: 'inputs' is just a static folder of some files that are not generated by the build, they are put there manually.